# Javascript Line by line diff

Tags: javascript, diff

I have this javascript code from the user Harmen.

It's amazing how such a short code makes so god job.
http://jsfiddle.net/pfYtu/

I tried to edit it to make a line by line comparison, but the code have no comments and it's getting hard for me to understand the logic (of how it works). May the original coder could give me some suggestions.

What I mean by line by line?
Currently it is displaying the result as a single column of a table, well, i want it in two columns.
Here is the original source code.

```
// http://harmen.no-ip.org/javascripts/diff/
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462609
function diff_text(text1, text2) {
  var table = '';

  function make_row(x, y, type, text) {
    if (type == ' ') console.log(x, y);
    var row = '<tr';
    if (type == '+') row += ' class="add"';
    else if (type == '-') row += ' class="del"';
    row += '>';

    row += '<td class="lineno">' + y;
    row += '<td class="lineno">' + x;
    row += '<td class="difftext">' + type + ' ' + text;

    table += row;
  }

  function get_diff(matrix, a1, a2, x, y) {
    if (x > 0 && y > 0 && a1[y-1] === a2[x-1]) {
      get_diff(matrix, a1, a2, x-1, y-1);
      make_row(x, y, ' ', a1[y-1]);
    }
    else {
      if (x > 0 && (y === 0 || matrix[y][x-1] >= matrix[y-1][x])) {
        get_diff(matrix, a1, a2, x-1, y);
        make_row(x, '', '+', a2[x-1]);
      }
      else if (y > 0 && (x === 0 || matrix[y][x-1] < matrix[y-1][x])) {
        get_diff(matrix, a1, a2, x, y-1);
        make_row('', y, '-', a1[y-1]);
      }
      else {
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  function diff(a1, a2) {
    var matrix = new Array(a1.length + 1);
    var x, y;

    for (y = 0; y < matrix.length; y++) {
      matrix[y] = new Array(a2.length + 1);

      for (x = 0; x < matrix[y].length; x++) {
        matrix[y][x] = 0;
      }
    }

    for (y = 1; y < matrix.length; y++) {
      for (x = 1; x < matrix[y].length; x++) {
        if (a1[y-1] === a2[x-1]) {
          matrix[y][x] = 1 + matrix[y-1][x-1];
        }
        else {
          matrix[y][x] = Math.max(matrix[y-1][x], matrix[y][x-1]);
        }
      }
    }

    get_diff(matrix, a1, a2, x-1, y-1);
  }

  diff(text1.split('\n'), text2.split('\n'));
  return '<table class="diff_text">' + table + '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this make_row function... it gives results in 2 columns.

```js
function make_row(x, y, type, text) {
    if (type == " ") console.log(x, y);
    var row = "<tr";
    if (type == "+") row += ' class="add"';
    else if (type == "-") row += ' class="del"';
    row += ">";

    row += '<td class="lineno">' + y;
    row += '<td class="lineno">' + x;
    if (type == " ") {
        row += '<td class="difftext">' + type + " " + text;
        row += '<td class="difftext">' + type + " " + text;
    }

    if (type == "+") {
        row += '<td class="difftext">' + " ";
        row += '<td class="difftext">' + type + " " + text;
    }

    if (type == "-") {
        row += '<td class="difftext">' + type + " " + text;
        row += '<td class="difftext">' + " ";
    }

    table += row;
}
```

Comment: Wow! this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. When things are done, they looks obvious, but is not so obvious to get the actual solution!

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [Google's diff_match_patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) library - it's very efficient and works wonderfully well. It can produce diffs from a machine as well as a human's perspective.

Recently used it in a project. The API is a little bit of a pain - so I wrote a jQuery library to wrap the calls: https://github.com/arnab/jQuery.PrettyTextDiff/.

Here's a [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arnab/YwSVY/). Basically all you'll need to do is:

```
$(<selector>).prettyTextDiff({
    // options
});
```

If you use it and have questions, please ask here (or in GH issues).

Comment: Thank you very  much arnab for your tip. I took a look at google's API and it's very powerful, however I discarded it because I wanted face to face line diff. But after seeing your demo I realized that I can display the original one in one side and the result in the other. I'll take a look to your library.

Comment: Cool. Hope you use it. Let me know via GH issues if you have trouble.

Comment: Is there a way to get simply the row and column of the first difference using this library? `var d = dmp.diff_main(myText, otherText, false);` shown in the examples returns a confounding array of values.